# Parse.com cloud code accessing user object in query result is null

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

So I'm making a query to a table that I have for followers. Each result in the array has a userA and a userB object in it. When I try to access the userB object, it's null. However, when I access the elements of the array, userB shows...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFeed", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  /***********************************
  **** GETTING FRIENDS LIST
  ***********************************/
  var query = new Parse.Query("Follow");
  var user = {"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User", 'objectId':request.params.user};
  query.equalTo("userA",user);
  query.include("userB");
  query.find({
    success: function(follows) {
      /***********************************
      **** GETTING FRIENDS' UPDATES
      ***********************************/
      //var feedUser = [];
      console.log("FOLLOWS: "+follows);
      console.log("FIRST FOLLOW *******"+follows[0]);
      console.log("USER B VALUE ********"+follows[0].userB);
      response.success(follows);
      // for(var i in follows) {
      //     feedUser.push(i.userB);
      // }


      // var queryUpdate = new Parse.Query("Goal");
      // queryUpdate.containedIn("user",feedUser);
      // queryUpdate.find({
      //   success: function(results) {
      //     response.success(friends);
      //   },
      //   error: function(error) {
      //     response.error(error);
      //   }
      // })
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error(error);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***userB*** doesn't reside directly on it's parent object, so it's not accessible via

```
follows[0].userB
```

You'll need to properly traverse the object structure. When you include an object from another data class via a Pointer, the object will actually reside within the *attributes* property of it's parent object, so you'll need to access it like so:

```
follows[0].attributes.userB
```

Cheers!